# Shorten the XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

I have a XML and a corresponding XSD as follows:

myXSD.xsd :

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/myXSD"
    xmlns="http://www.example.com/myXSD"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="RootElem">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>

                <xs:element name="Insider1">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element ref="Internal" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>

                <xs:element name="Insider2">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element ref="Internal" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>

                <xs:element name="Insider3">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element ref="Internal" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>

            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="Internal-low">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="myString" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="unbounded"></xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="Internal">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Step" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                <xs:element ref="Internal-low" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

myXML.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<RootElem xmlns="http://www.example.com/myXSD"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/myXSD myXSD.xsd">
    <Insider1>
        <Internal>
            <Step>My step 1</Step>
            <Internal-low>
                <myString>My string 1 for step 1</myString>
            </Internal-low>
        </Internal>
        <Internal>
            <Step>My step 2</Step>
            <Internal-low>
                <myString>My string 1 for step 2</myString>
            </Internal-low>
        </Internal>
        <Internal>
            <Step>My step 3</Step>
            <Internal-low>
                <myString>My string 1 for step 3</myString>
                <myString>My string 2 for step 3</myString>
            </Internal-low>
        </Internal>
    </Insider1>
    <Insider2>
        <Internal>
            <Step>My step 1</Step>
            <Internal-low>
                <myString>My string 1 for step 1</myString>
            </Internal-low>
        </Internal>
        <Internal>
            <Step>My step 2</Step>
            <Internal-low>
                <myString>My string 1 for step 2</myString>
            </Internal-low>
        </Internal>
        <Internal>
            <Step>My step 3</Step>
            <Internal-low>
                <myString>My string 1 for step 3</myString>
                <myString>My string 2 for step 3</myString>
            </Internal-low>
        </Internal>
    </Insider2>
    <Insider3>
        <Internal>
            <Step>My step 1</Step>
            <Internal-low>
                <myString>My string 1 for step 1</myString>
            </Internal-low>
        </Internal>
        <Internal>
            <Step>My step 2</Step>
            <Internal-low>
                <myString>My string 1 for step 2</myString>
            </Internal-low>
        </Internal>
        <Internal>
            <Step>My step 3</Step>
            <Internal-low>
                <myString>My string 1 for step 3</myString>
                <myString>My string 2 for step 3</myString>
            </Internal-low>
        </Internal>
    </Insider3>

</RootElem>
```

Everything works fine here. The problem is with the `InsiderX` elements. There are about 10 `InsiderX` elements in my actual XSD which may be increasing over time. So I need to compress the XSD code so that adding or removing any `InsiderX` element is simpler as doing so now requires adding/removing 7 lines of redundant code. And how can I make sure that one and only one of each of the `InsiderX` element occurs in my XML.

Also I would like to know what are other options in a XSD to replace `<xs:sequence>`. I don't want alternate to this, but want to know what are other possible options like `<xs:choice>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to compress the XSD code so that adding or removing any
>   InsiderX element is simpler as doing so now requires adding/removing 7
>   lines of redundant code

You can shorten your XSD by creating a reusable type like this.

```
<xs:complexType name="InsiderXType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="Internal" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="RootElem">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Insider1" type="InsiderXType"/>
            <xs:element name="Insider2" type="InsiderXType"/>
            <xs:element name="Insider3" type="InsiderXType"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

> how can I make sure that one and only one of each of the InsiderX
>   element occurs in my XML

You've already covered this scenario with your original schema. Modify your XML document by duplicating the *Insider1* node for example like this

```
<Insider1>
    ...
</Insider1>
<Insider1>
    ...
</Insider1>
<Insider2>
   ...
```

and try to validate this against your schema. You'll get an error something like this: *cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'Insider1'. One of '{"http://www.example.com/myXSD":Insider2}' is expected.*

> I would like to know what are other options in a XSD to replace
>   <xs:sequence>

Well I'm not sure how to answer this, because this question is really too broad, however take a look at the [XML Schema specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#declare-type) for complex type definitions. It says that instead of a sequence you can use *group*, *all* or *choice*. I hope this will get you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's undoable, a better way to handle this would be in your xml to have :

```
<Insider name="Insider1">
```

instead of

```
<Insider1>
```

**EDIT :** (restrict name attribute values)

```
<attribute name="name">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="Insider[0-9]*"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</attribute>
```

Comment: OK, but how can I limit the name value to only `Insider1`, `Insider2` & `Insider3`??

Comment: @Mukund : I edited my answer to restrict the name values

Comment: It is ok for this case but I actually intend to get a generalised solution where my names could be "ABC", "PQR" & "XYZ". So a regex pattern cannot suffice my need. I need to restrict values on the basis of what exactly I give.